# Diagonalization of a block hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, svd, block-matrices, hermitian-matrices

Suppose $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times m}$ has a singular value decomposition: $A=U \Sigma V^H$. Find diagonalization of a block hermitian matrix $B\in \mathbb{C}^{2m\times 2m}$, $B=[0 \; \; A^H; A \; \; 0]$.

I am kind of lost on this problem. I was thinking about writing $B=[0 \; \;  (U\Sigma V^H)^H; U\Sigma V^H\; \; 0]$, but not sure where to go from there, I hope someone can help me get on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been searching on a similar question and found [this approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473073/finding-an-eigenvalue-decomposition-of-a-2m-times-2m-hermitian-matrix?rq=1) helpful:

(Note that in the link, the $A^H$ and $A$ block matrices are swapped.)

I'm still a student myself, but since there are no other answers here yet, perhaps this will help you as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot

Comment: @kcp33 You're welcome! I'm glad.